# Concatenate power query columns that are offset from each other

Tags: excel, concatenation, powerquery

***The problem***

I have a data set with two header rows. I've transposed the rows into columns to work with the headers before combining, but I need help with concatenation of `column1` into `column2`, since past row 7 the columns are offset from one another by one row (see example image).

***The goal***

I've tried to use replace and concatenate myself with an index, but have been unable to achieve the desired end result where `column2 row 8` is concatenated with `column1 row 7`, so that when I combine these columns and transpose again the headers will be correctly labeled (see example image).

Thank you for any suggestions and your time.

Example image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's *one* way.

I start with your Problem table as a table named Table1:

[image]

Then I add an index. (Add Column > Index Column):

[image]

Then I add a custom column. (Add Column > Custom Column) With this setup:

[image]

*(`#"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Column1]` references the entry in Column1 at the position record row that is equal to the value in the Index column, minus 1.)*

...to get this:

[image]

Then I *replaced* Errors in the new Custom column. (Right-click Custom column title > click *Replace* Errors > type null > click OK)

[image]

Then I select Column1 and Custom column and remove other columns. (Select Column 1 column title > hold Ctrl and click Custom column title > keep holding Ctrl and right click Custom column title > click Remove Other Columns)

[image]

Here's my M code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Column1]&"-"&[Column2]),
#"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Added Custom", {{"Custom", null}}),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Replaced Errors",{"Column1", "Custom"})
in
#"Removed Other Columns"
```

Comment: Marc thank you for talking the time to lay this out step by step. I greatly appreciate being able to walk through each piece to understand how you arrived at the end result. Your solution worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    IndexedTable = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
    Transform = Table.TransformRows(IndexedTable, (row)=>[Column1= row[Column1], Column2 = if row[Column1]=null then Text.Combine({IndexedTable{row[Index]-1}[Column1], "-",row[Column2]}) else row[Column2]]),
    ToTable = Table.FromRecords(Transform)
in
    ToTable
```

Brief explanation:

1. Source
2. Add index to address previous record
3. Use `Table.TransformRows` to analyze and transform each row to a record in this manner: Column1 taken from each row's column1 (`row[Column1]`), Column2 is generated from previous row using `Text.Concatenate`,  `IndexedTable{row[Index]-1}[Column1]`. This yields value from previous row's Column1. `Table.TransformRows` returns list of records.
4. Transform list of records into the table.

This code will fail if 1st row contains null in [Column1]. If this is unacceptable, add another `if-then-else`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    fillDown = Table.FillDown(Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "Column1", "copy"),{"copy"}),
    replace = Table.ReplaceValue(fillDown, each [Column2], each if [Column2] = null then null
              else [copy]&"-"&[Column2], Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"Column2"})[[Column1],[Column2]]
in
    replace
```